# single-row subquery returns more than one row Oracle Database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

i have two tables namely PESANMASUK anda KONTAK. in PESANMASUK i have 5 fileds : **IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN** .
and KONTAK i have 3 fileds : **IDKONTAK, NAMA, NOHP**.

PESANMASUK table Data:

```
IDMASUK TANGGALMASUK    JAM     NOMERHP     ISIPESAN
1       09/08/2015      09:00   +62847776   try sms
2       08/08/2015      10:00   +62856790   plase come in
3       08/08/2015      06:00   +6283444    you and me
```

KONTAK table data :

```
IDKONTAK    NAMA        NOHP
1           RIAN        +62847776
2           ALFIAN      +62856790
```

this result is i want :

```
IDMASUK TANGGALMASUK    JAM     NOMERHP     NAMA        ISIPESAN
1       09/08/2015      09:00   +62847776   RIAN        try sms
2       08/08/2015      10:00   +62856790   ALFIAN      plase come in
3       08/08/2015      06:00   +6283444                you and me
```

this is my oracle query :

```
SELECT IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN, 
(SELECT NAMA FROM KONTAK WHERE NOHP IN (SELECT NOMERHP FROM PESANMASUK)) AS NAMA 
FROM PESANMASUK
```

I got error like this :

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I wanna matching between NOMERHP in PESANMASUK  and NAMA in KONTAK and return all rows.

how can I solve this??

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited for my question,..plase suggest me how to solve this,..i tried fro your query below using listagg() but NAMA still have blank result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.:)

Left join gets the details or row on the left table even if it has no matching data on the right table.

Please browse the link below for more information regarding left join.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
select idmasuk, tanggalmasuk, jam, nomerhp, nama, isipesan
from 
pesanmasuk
left join kontak
on pesanmasuk.nomerhp = kontak.nohp;
```

Hope it helps. Cheers! :)

Comment: yes that's work....thanks,...no rolation between two tables but using left join it work....nice...

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for letting me know the result. Glad I could help.  :D

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the subquery is returning more than one row.  Here are two ways to fix it:

```
SELECT IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN, 
       (SELECT MAX(NAMA) FROM KONTAK WHERE NOHP IN (SELECT NOMERHP FROM PESANMASUK)) AS NAMA 
FROM PESANMASUK;
```

or:

```
SELECT IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN, 
       (SELECT NAMA FROM KONTAK WHERE NOHP IN (SELECT NOMERHP FROM PESANMASUK WHERE ROWNUM = 1)) AS NAMA 
FROM PESANMASUK;
```

My guess, though, is that neither does what you want and you really want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN, 
       (SELECT k.NAMA FROM KONTAK k WHERE k.NOHP = p.NOMERHP) AS NAMA 
FROM PESANMASUK p
```

EDIT:

To get all the names, you can use `listagg()`:

```
SELECT IDMASUK, TANGGALMASUK, JAM, NOMERHP, ISIPESAN, 
       (SELECT LISTAGG(k.NAMA, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY k.NAMA)
        FROM KONTAK k
        WHERE k.NOHP = p.NOMERHP) AS NAMA 
FROM PESANMASUK p
```

Comment: i wanna matching all value between two table like this result : [1, 10/08/09, +620522611111, RIAN, TES], [2, 10/08/09, +6283888888, FIAN, TRY SMS] . rian and fian is from KONTAK table that was matching from NOMERHP in PESANMASUK table

Comment: the last query that you suggest is i want, return all rows in query. but it still dind't work. the error is same `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: You can add `and rownum = 1` in the subquery.

Comment: if i add rownum = 1 it will result just one name (NAMA) no all,..in this case i will display all name from kontak table that was matching in pesanmasuk NOMERHP

Comment: using `LISTAGG()` it almost finish,..query woks.... but NAMA still blank result,... but it help me,..
i got a clue....

Comment: Gordon Linoff : i have updated for my question,...can you help me again how to solve this?